# probleme to cach my remote website with varnish

Tags: caching, webserver, varnish, remote-server

i ihave one week to configure varnish to cach my website remotly

i try a lot of configuration but nothing i don't have any cache i d'ont get any explication

so my configuration is

```
enter code here


backend default {

.host ="axelaris-hosting.com";
.port = "80";
.connect_timeout = 600s;
.first_byte_timeout = 600s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    }
    else {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
}
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~       "\.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|cgi|ico)$") {
            unset req.http.cookie;
            return (lookup);
    }
}
sub vcl_fetch {
    if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
    if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~\.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|cgi|ico)$") {
            unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
            set beresp.ttl = 7d;
            return(deliver);
    }
```

also my second question i need to install om my local machine nginx to cache my remote website?

see this screen shhot to undrestand my problem

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=251218varnish.png

varnih dosen't cache any content localy

help please

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://www.axelaris-hosting.com/ the scripts are loaded using the full URL. For example:

```
<script src="http://www.axelaris-hosting.com/templates/axelaris-hosting-blue2/js/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That's why they are not loaded through your local Varnish cache.

Varnish isn't really designed to do what you're planning to use it for.

You might want to look at running [Squid as a transparent proxy](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer have you please other solution to what i need? Best Regards

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you could set up Squid in your LAN and use it as a proxy server.